# Incorrect Syntax in sql server , can't figure out the reason

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I'm trying to uodate a column in table , depending on combination of two columns.If the value was null , since beginning of time I set it to 0 otherwise I set it to max value until that date.I'm using SQL SERVER 2008.Thanks for the help in advance!

```
  update Table1
  set value = a.value
 from
     ( SELECT product, 
     week , 
         case when  value is null then 
                (case when  max(value) over(PARTITION BY product                ORDER        BY       week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) is null then 0 
                 else (max(value) over (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) end )  
           else value  end as value
  from table2 ) a
   where a.product = table1.product
        and a.week = table1.week
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is Incorrect syntax near ROWS

Answer (score 1):

The `ROWS` keyword was added to the `OVER` clause in 2012.  You won't be able to use it for 2008.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx